# How to apply texture to one face of an object in cycles render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv

I can find dozen of tutorials on how to apply texture to one face of an object in Blender Render, but nothing for Cycles Render!
 I selected the faces I wanted, added material, chose an image texture, brought up the uv editing screen, did the smart uv project, made sure the correct texture was selected.

Didn't work; the object is still 100% the first texture I had applied.

Any tips?

Comment: You will need to use either a separate material or a different UV map

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the material to selected faces in the materials tab.

[image]